# How to upgrade Graphite

Tags: graphite, graphite-carbon

Ok, this one seems really simple but I don't know where to begin.

My current Graphite version is 0.9.12 and I want to upgrade to 0.9.14. My OS is Ubuntu 14.

There *is* a documentation: http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/0_9_14.html

But it doesn't say what we need to do with the previous packages. So, what shall I do? Remove them? Simply install the new packages? Which files shall I keep/remove?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I tried doing it with pip.

```
pip install 'graphite-web==0.9.14'
pip install 'carbon==0.9.14'
pip install 'whisper==0.9.14'
```

First, it didn't work, I was getting an error message:

```
Not uninstalling graphite-web at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

I found out my pip version was very old (1.5.4). Actually, *the version of pip in the Ubuntu repositories is only 1.5.4*, so **I uninstalled pip and reinstalled a new version of it** (9.0.1... what a giant leap :p)

Then, I launched the previous commands and they were successful.

It was possible to check it by running `pip list`, which lists the packages and displays their version.

Hopefully, this personal adventure will help someone someday (most likely me in one or two months).